# show dropdown with a pre-selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pre-select a value in a dropdown. I retrieve the selected value from DB. I could not pre-select the value as desired. Can you please help me in fixing this ?

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="reportType.consolidationScopeId">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option ng-repeat="consolidationScope in consolidationScopes" value="{{consolidationScope.consolScopeId}}">{{consolidationScope.consolScopeLabel}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
$http.get("/mdmservice/services/consolidationScopes")
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.consolidationScopes = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see 3 different examples for select tag using AngularJS:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xc8Qrcr0AN4I2U0chbye?p=preview

Notice that you can use `ng-selected` or just use `ng-model`